How can I give a shadow outline to the selected option in SegmentedButton (Flutter)?
I am trying to give a shadow outline to the selected option in a SegmentedButton in Flutter. So far, this is what I have tried, changing the code in the second example of the SegmentedButton:
return SegmentedButton<Calendar>(
  style: SegmentedButton.styleFrom(
    shadowColor:Colors.red, //I have added this
    elevation:1.0, //I added this
    surfaceTintColor: Colors.red, //I added this
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200], 
    foregroundColor: Colors.grey,
    selectedForegroundColor: Colors.black,
    selectedBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
  ),

which gives the following output:

How can I make it so that the selected option also has a shadow outline around it?
Edit:
I want it to be something like this, the white one is selected, whereas yellow is unselected. This is what I want: When I click on 'Day', it turns white, and it has a shadow border around it.

Similarly, when I click on 'Week', it turns white, and has a shadow border around it:

I am able to give the white color, but unable to give the shadow border in SegmentedButton.

can you share the image or something how you want the design to be?

I have added an image which tells how I want the design to be like.

for this don't use SegmentedButton you can create this with custom container.

You can use a Container with a BoxDecoration?
Here you have a sample: How to add Shadows to SegmentedButton in Flutter
With a GestureDetector and Container you also can create your own widget.

Yes, that is the approach I eventually ended up going with
